# Spring Batch: dynamic composite reader/processor/writer

Tags: spring-batch

I've seen [this (2010)](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/82170-set-itemreaders-dynamically) and [this (SO, 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955363/dynamically-choose-a-spring-batch-reader-at-runtime), but still have not got the answer I need...

Is there an option in Spring Batch to have a dynamic composite reader/processor/writer?

The idea is to have the ability to replace processor at runtime, and in case of multiple processors (AKA composite-processor), to have the option to add/remove/replace/change order of processors. As mentioned, same for reader/writer.

I thought of something like reading the processors list from DB (using cache?) and there the items (beans' names) can be changed. Does this make sense?

**EDIT - why do I need this?**

There are cases that I use processors as "filters", and it may occur that the business (the client) may change the requirements (yes, it is very annoying) and ask to switch among filters (change the priority). 

Other use case is having multiple readers to get the data from different data warehouse, and again - the client changes the warehouse from time to time (integration phase), and I do not want my app to be restarted each and every time. 
There are many other use cases, of course. [plus this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955363/dynamically-choose-a-spring-batch-reader-at-runtime)

Thanks

Comment: What's the intend of doing that? Usually batch jobs are static. Maybe Spring Batch is not the right tool. If you tell me a bit more of your requirements I can advise.

Comment: there are cases that I use processors as "filters", and it may occur that the business (the client) may change the requirements (yes, it is very annoying) and ask to switch among filters (change the priority). Other use case is having multiple readers to get the data from different data warehouse, and again - the client changes the warehouse from time to time (integration phase). so I do not want my app to be restarted each and every time.

Comment: but then you don't need to exchange the processor. But your processor can choose what kind of code to execute. and also in the reader you can change the data source

Comment: @simas_ch so u suggest a single processor that will dynamically decide what code to run. what is the difference then? we still end up with the same challenge...

Comment: why? you can't create the batch job dynamically but if you have the processor that can handle everything dynamically. you could even read the code from the database.

Comment: @simas_ch mmm... not crazy about it, but it is an option.

Comment: Why do think it would be better if you can dynamically create a job?

Comment: coz i think that a spring-batch-integrated ("built in") solution could be better

Comment: Batch jobs are static and job and step executions are logged. From an operating perspective a dynamic job is a bad thing

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2644

Comment: When I read your JIRA issue I'm not sure if probably you are doing integration with batch. Have you ever thought to use Apache Camel or Spring Integration to solve your problem?

Comment: actually no... should I? i thiought this could be a nice add-on to apring-batch, or another capability of spring-batch...

Comment: It's not easy to distinguish between enterprise application integration and batch processing. Do you know this: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've started working on this project:

https://github.com/OhadR/spring-batch-dynamic-composite

that implements the requirements in the question above. If someone wanna contribute - feel free!